# how can I check which attributes are accessible for my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am doing some metaprogramming where I add accessible attributes to a model and would like to know how to check and see whether these attributes are accessible.

Looked at the documentation but could find no reference.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_accessible

I know I can do something like `object.instance_methods` but that dozen't really filter it down to accessible.

Is there some method that will return the accessible attributes?

Answer (score 1):

Use `accessible_attributes` and `protected_attributes`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name
end

User.accessible_attributes
# => #<ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::WhiteList: {"", "first_name", "last_name"}>

User.protected_attributes
# => #<ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::BlackList: {"id", "type"}>
```

If you call `attr_protected` and not `attr_accessible` in your class, then ALL of your attributes except for those in your Blacklist will be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `User` model with these attributes: `:id, :lastname, :firstname, :email`
and your model class is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :lastname, :firstname
end
```

You can have the accessible list like this:

```
User.attr_accessible[:default].to_a
=> [:lastname, :firstname]
```

Moreover you can have the list of no-accessible attributes:

```
User.new.attributes.keys - User.attr_accessible[:default].to_
=> [:id, :email]
```

I hope this help